# How to install scikit-learn with version = 018.dev0 with pip?

Tags: python, installation, scikit-learn

I have installed scikit-learn by following command using pip

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

When I check the version its.

```
>>> sklearn.__version__
'0.17.1'
```

- The installed scikit-learn and by default it has downloaded version 0.17.1 
  I am trying to use Multi-layer Perceptron which is available in version 0.18.dev0 as pre the documentation
- When I try to install by specifing the version like below:

  pip install scikit-learn==0.18.dev0
- The error is:

  Collecting scikit-learn==0.18.dev0
  C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
    SNIMissingWarning
  C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
    InsecurePlatformWarning
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scikit-learn==0.18.dev0 (from versions: 0.9, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.13, 0.13.1, 0.14, 0.14.1, 0.15.0b1, 0.15.0b2, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16b1, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.17b1, 0.17, 0.17.1)
  No matching distribution found for scikit-learn==0.18.dev0
  C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
    InsecurePlatformWarning
- How do I install scikit-learn version == 0.18.dev0 with pip?

Comment: `pip` by default only installs libraries that are released on PyPI, which dev versions often are not, and it appears scikit 0.18 [is not](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-learn).  You could look up how to install a github repo with pip.

Comment: try installing it from github like `pip install git+git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn@master`